# Extract number between 2nd space and "," in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a r data frame. One of its column "A" has string. I would like to extract the number between **second** space in string and **","**.

The data frame looks like

```
       A        
XY Z 123, 30009 Addr
AB CBA 12, 900000 Addr
FC AX 1234, 977777 Addr
.
.
```

And the resultant df should look like

```
       A
123
12
1234
.
.
```

The numbers that need to be extracted are not fixed in length.

Comment: Please share the code where you got stuck and explain what is wrong with it. It also seems you just want to get the first chunk of digits in those strings, it looks a much simpler task then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was planning to do it using regex. I have other ways around of this. I have not written as code for this as of now as I am new to regex.

Comment: Please read [Learning Regular Expressions](//stackoverflow.com/q/4736), [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is also good to learn regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You might want to see [this transcript from SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34889602#34889602). You're welcome there to discuss if anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Match one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`) that are repeated twice (`{2}`) followed by one or more numbers captured as a group (`(\\d+)`) followed by a `,` and other characters until the end of the string and replace it with the backreference of the second captured group (`\\2`)

```
df1$A <- as.numeric(sub("(\\S+\\s+){2}(\\d+),.*", "\\2", df1$A))
df1$A
#[1]  123   12 1234
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("XY Z 123, 30009 Addr", "AB CBA 12, 900000 Addr", 
"FC AX 1234, 977777 Addr")), .Names = "A", class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Can you please explain the **{2}** use. if we are already comparing using (\\S+\\s+) then why we need **{2}**. 
Also this is giving me "NA" . Any reason

Comment: @KshitijMarwah  The `\\S+\\s+` matches the first non-whitespace characters and whitespace characters that follow it, but you want to get the numbers that comes after the second white space, so using this `{2}`, it will match the same as `\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+`